# When do we use 'extends' in a class in android

Tags: java, inheritance

Why and when do we use `extends` in android?

`public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {....`

Like this, why do we use `extends ListActivity` here?

Comment: You need to learn Java.

Comment: Agree.. I cannot understand why people try to learn Android before Java. IT IS JAVA.

Comment: @Enrichman Because Android is far more appealing than boring old Java. I agree, it's kind of crazy and it applies to everything in this world. You don't learn how to ride a motorcycle before you learn how to ride a bike. Learn the basics first.

Comment: Yeah i forgot about inheritance.Now i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `extends` when we want to create a subclass of some class, and this is not android-specific, but part of Java. You might want to follow [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Activity` has a `ListActivity` and you want the `Activity` features as well as those associated with a ListActivity like using [getListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

`ListActivity extends Activity` so you get all of the `Activity` methods still.

So if you want to create an `AsyncTask` then you use `extends AsyncTask<params>` to have access to the `AsyncTask` methods and such.